# Firefox / Flash plugin

Tags: html, flash, firefox, firefox-addon

I am using a moving flash logo on my website. I am using the code below:

```
 <object width="248px" height="148px" id="flashContent">
      <param name="movie" value="http://domain.co.uk/flash/Flash_logo.swf">
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://domain.co.uk/flash/Flash_logo.swf" width="248px" height="148px">
        <param name="movie" value="http://domain.co.uk/flash/Flash_logo.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <img src="images/global/logo.png"/>
      </object>
    </object>
```

Basically the code above will show the flash logo unless flash is not available.In which case the image logo.png will be used as a replacement. This works perfectly fine. However problems arise with Firefox when it detects that flash is not up to date.

Instead of showing the flash file or the logo.png firefox displays a big box stating that the plugin is vulnerable and must be updated. To be honest my flash files serves not other function that to add a little extra style to the site and with the plugin problem my site loads without a logo at all which is less than ideal.

I suppose my question is... Is it possible to edit my code above so that if the plug in is out of date then just the logo.png is loaded instead of Firefox detecting the plugin problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not just Firefox and/or outdated Flash.
Users can set any plugin incl. Flash to click-to-play in recent Firefox versions, not just outdated ones.
Chrome also has a preference that allows you to set plugins to "click-to-play".

There is no reliable way to detect click-to-play (due to outdated plugins and/or user preferences), neither in Firefox nor Chrome.

Sometimes it is recommended to construct a plugin in javascript, wait for it to load and then try to interact with it, and if that fails go to a fallback method. However, you still cannot distinguish between the plugin being autoloaded and the user just being a fast clicker.

Your best option is not to use Flash at all, if you don't really need it or it doesn't worth the fuzz. Otherwise try the detection thing.